# Turn of sslstrip

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have been so incredibly dumb to hack my self and now I can't turn it off. I have been doing an online tutorial on ethical hacking. 
I have pre-routed HTTPS to HTTP on my own OS. :S

Code:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING

ifconfig wlp2s0
route
router gateway adrdess 192.168.1.1 
nmap 192.168.1.2-254 -vv
```

I have turned echo 1 back to echo 0 but it dosen't help.

Is there a way to turn iptables back to standard settings?
Or any other way to stop the prerouting?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The steps would be:

1. set the default policies for each of the built-in chains to `ACCEPT`. The main reason to do this is to ensure that you won't be locked out from your server via SSH (for good practice):

   ```
   sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
   ```
2. Then flush the `nat` and `mangle tables`, flush all chains (`-F`), and delete all `non-default chains (-X)`:

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -F
   sudo iptables -t mangle -F
   sudo iptables -F
   sudo iptables -X
   ```

Source:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly fast answer. I believe it works like a charm. Is there a way to make 100% sure? Thanks.

Comment: If it helped please accept the answer

Comment: Use `sudo iptables -S` to list the current rules